# Django - Many to Many Field Ordering Issue

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

```
class Sandeep(models.Model):
model_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
processors2 = models.ManyToManyField(ConfiguratorProduct,blank=True,  
related_name="processors2", verbose_name="Processors2")

model_sk= models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
model_dk = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
model_pk = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True).contribute_to_class(
Sandeep.processors2.through, 'date_added2')
```

The above is my model and I am using processors2 as a Many to many Field. I want to save many to many field in the same order which i am adding to Sandeep from django Admin but my order get shuffled by the default id of ConfiguratorProduct[Manyto many relation model]

I tried using the above statement and successfully added one new field timestamp but not able to get the data into django admin UI as per the time-stamp.

I have checked so many solutions but not able to find out the best way to display many to many field in the same order which I am adding to the Model.

Comment: Anyone, who knows the solution?

Comment: How are you adding the models in the admin? With an inline panel?

Comment: Yes, I am adding from Django admin

Comment: Still looking for a solution.